# limit number of characters entered in cognos search and select prompt

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

limit number of characters entered in cognos search and select prompt

```
`The below script works for text box.
<script>
// The ASDF here comes from the Name property of the prompt
var fW = (typeof getFormWarpRequest == "function" ? getFormWarpRequest() :
document.forms["formWarpRequest"]);  
fW._textEditBoxASDF.maxLength = 3;  
</script>`
```

I need a similiar piece of code to work with Search and select prompt.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have cognos in front of me but let me tell you how i did stuff like this with Javascript. Please read entirely as there are several approaches.

1. Put a uniquely named/id DIV tag around your native Cognos select and search prompt(The one your typing in.  This will make it easy to reference with Java's dom model for the next steps.  We will eventually make this default search prompt invisible/hidden but for now keep it visible until the following steps are coded/debugged.
2. Create an HTML control in the simliar style as the native Select and search with the proper max-length settings that you want.  Use the text box on change event to update the native Cognos select and search prompt.  for debugging troubleshooting i find it handy to have javascript alert the DIV innerHTML so you can see whats under the hood with the Cognos control.  Sometimes i uses this innerHTML as the starting point for my "Cloned/Shadow" HTML prompt that i have control over.
3. Once you have your new HTML control effectively changing the Cognos control you can make it invisible.

   - - On complex dashboards/scorecarding i wrote routines to clone cognos prompts and expose their HTML so i could create my own control that would quietly manipulate the actual hidden controls.  This gave me complete control over presentation and functionality.
   - - There are many variations on this once you have the controls innerhtml like replacing the innerHTML with one of your own immediately after the page loads that has the restrictions on length.  Or simply seeing if you can massage the property learning from the innerhtml.
   - - In Cognos 8.4 and 10 there is a new method to dynamically add a method to a control to be called prior to any other methods.  It is tricky but it is on IBM's web site.  I may be more cleanly implemented in 10 and also IBM is not shy about showing off these solutions on their web site.